# Sending XML data to web service

Tags: c#, xml, api, rest, soap

am posting XML file to Web services using C# .
My work is generating a xml file from object of my application then I should send it on the business Gateway of Monster.com .
I tried this method for sending but I encountred an error

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
> Please Help !

```
public void sendFileToWebservice(string file)
{
    string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/DELL/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/testXML/testXML/file.xml");
    string url = "https://gateway.monster.com:8443/bgwBroker";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);


    byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlString);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();


    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
    string backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    res.Close();
}
```

Comment: they should have sample code. maybe the POST need to be authorized.

Comment: If [this is the service](https://partner.monster.com/real-time-posting-devguide) you are using then your request is way off. You need to send a SOAP request with credentials in the SOAP header. They should be able to provide you with a wsdl file that you can use to generate a proxy client.

Comment: See Authentication and Authorization.  You are missing parameters in the URL : https://partner.monster.com/job-search